# Split an existing prompt command line in a few lines

Tags: bash, command-line

I understand I can type `\` <kbd>enter</kbd> at the end of a `bash` command line to continue that command in another line. But how can I split a **prompt** command line — that has already been fully typed — into two?

For example, how can I break this line right before `then` without having to cut the remainder off and type it all over again?

```
$ if true; then ls; fi
```

Comment: If you are at an interactive command line prompt, is there any particular reason you need to do this besides making your shell history look prettier?  Functionally, extra newlines make no difference to the shell.  If you are typing a long complex shell snippet, it's best to use an editor.  Look into the `fc` command as well - it is available in nearly all shells.

Comment: Not prettier but just to make complex commands readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character is LF (line feed), a.k.a. Control-J. If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, this executes the command `accept-line`, same as the <kbd>Return</kbd> key. To insert a literal LF character, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. The command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> ([`quoted-insert`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-Text)) inserts the next character literally. Thus, to split a line, you can enter 
<kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

If you do this often, you can make it a macro:

```
bind '"\e\C-j": "\\\C-v\C-j\C-b\C-b"'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `edit-and-execute-command`, usually mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, to **open the current command in an editor**. When exiting the editor the command will be run.

Comment: Nice - never knew this. You'll need to make sure your $EDITOR environment variable is set to something - I added `vim` to mine like so: `export EDITOR=vim`.

Comment: How can I cancel the execution of the command at exit of the editor? I use `:q!` or `ZQ` but of no avail.

Comment: @Birei: Delete all the lines then save and exit (e.g. `ggdG:wq` or `:%d|wq`, etc.). The command will remain in history (possibly as a duplicate if you recalled it from an earlier entry), but it won't be executed.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Wow!! Nearly three years later I yet hadn't solved this issue, so many thanks because the solution was so simple, and simplicity is always better.

Answer (score 2):

**Note - this answer specific to vi and vim**

```
set -o vi    # edit commands using vi
VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim
```

To edit the current typed line, hit `ESC` (to get into `vi` or `vim` command mode), then type `v` or `vi`.

Note all the vi/vim edit commands work. e.g.

- `ESC` + `A`  puts to the end of the current typed line.
- `ESC` + `0`  puts the cursor at the start of the line.

Comment: Excellent. This definitely makes editing command lines much easier. But do you know how to insert a new line character without going into visual mode?

Comment: Thanks. `CTRL` + `v` then `CTRL` + `j` to throw a newline should work.