# Why can't `paste` print stdin next to stderr?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, stderr, paste

Usually `paste` prints *two* named (or equivalent) files in adjacent columns like this:

```
paste <(printf '%s\n' a b) <(seq 2)
```

Output:

```
a   1
b   2
```

But when the two files are `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stderr`, it doesn't seem to work the same way.

Suppose we have ***b****lack****b****box* program which outputs two lines on *standard output* and two lines on *standard error*.  For illustration purposes, this can be simulated with a function:

```
bb() { seq 2 | tee >(sed 's/^/e/' > /dev/stderr) ; }
```

Now run [`annotate-output`](https://gist.github.com/jacksoncage/54743cf17121f6bc5b8eb3013dfd06ac), (in the *devscripts* package on *Debian/Ubuntu/etc.*), to show that it works:

```
annotate-output bash -c 'bb() { seq 2 | tee >(sed 's/^/e/' > /dev/stderr) ; }; bb'
22:06:17 I: Started bash -c bb() { seq 2 | tee >(sed s/^/e/ > /dev/stderr) ; }; bb
22:06:17 O: 1
22:06:17 E: e1
22:06:17 O: 2
22:06:17 E: e2
22:06:17 I: Finished with exitcode 0
```

So it works.  Feed `bb` to `paste`:

```
bb | paste /dev/stdin /dev/stderr
```

Output:

```
1   e1
e2
^C
```

It hangs -- `^C` means pressing *Control-C* to quit.

Changing the `|` to a `;` also doesn't work:

```
bb ; paste /dev/stdin /dev/stderr
```

Output:

```
1
2
e1
e2
^C
```

Also hangs -- `^C` means pressing *Control-C* to quit.

Desired output:

```
1    e1
2    e2
```

Can it be done using `paste`?  If not, why not?

Comment: Similar: [tee + cat: use an output several times and then concatenate results](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/66853)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split an input for different command and combine the result](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/183356)

Comment: You're never redirecting stderr, so it will probably be the terminal device if you run that from a terminal. Reading from a terminal device (like your `paste /dev/stderr` does) reads what you type on the keyboard, writing to it (like your `tee /dev/stderr` does) sends it for display by the terminal emulator.

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what you want to do? You can go with `for i in $(seq 2); do echo -n "$i " > /dev/stdout; echo e$i > /dev/stderr; done` and you will get the same effect

Comment: @Goro, Not a duplicate of that, since [Split an existing prompt command line in a few lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79696/split-an-existing-prompt-command-line-in-a-few-lines) has nothing to do with stderr.  Please retract.

Comment: @mrc02_kr, I don't want the same effect.  The question is: is it possible to do with `paste` or not possible?  A negative answer would be just as useful.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Thanks, [Split an input for different command and combine the result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183356) is certainly related, but it's really not about *stderr* as such.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Re *"You're never redirecting stderr..."*: did you mean that in the general sense, (it's impossible), or specific to this code, (*i.e.* the OP code doesn't do it, but perhaps should)?

Comment: It would need  a long answer to clear your confusions, but unfortunately I don't have time now. You can look at the linked Q&A for how to do it.

Comment: See also: [Why can't I read /dev/stdout with a text editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202263/why-cant-i-read-dev-stdout-with-a-text-editor)

Comment: in or out? (did you make an error in the question?)

Comment: @mosvy, Please post [your last comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474232/how-to-paste-stdin-next-to-stderr?noredirect=1#comment867027_474232) as an answer.

Comment: I don't see this as duplicate of mentioned questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why you can't use /dev/stderr as a pipeline

The problem isn't with `paste`, and neither is it with `/dev/stdin`.  It's with `/dev/stderr`.

All commands are created with one open input descriptor (0: standard input) and two outputs (1: standard output and 2: standard error).  Those can typically be accessed with the names `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` respectively, but see [How portable are /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/how-portable-are-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-and-dev-stderr).  Many commands, including `paste`, will also interpret the filename `-` to mean STDIN.

When you run `bb` on its own, both STDOUT and STDERR are the console, where command output usually appears.  The lines go through different descriptors (as shown by your `annotate-output`) but ultimately end up in the same place.

When you add a `|` and a second command, making a pipeline...

```
bb | paste /dev/stdin /dev/stderr
```

the `|` tells the shell to connect the output of `bb` to the input of `paste`.  `paste` first tries to read from `/dev/stdin`, which (via some symlinks) resolves to its own standard input descriptor (which the shell just connected up) so the line `1` comes through.

But the shell/pipeline does nothing to STDERR.  `bb` still sends that (`e1` `e2` etc.) to the console.  Meanwhile, `paste` attempts to read from the same console, which hangs (until you type something).

Your link [Why can't I read /dev/stdout with a text editor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202263/why-cant-i-read-dev-stdout-with-a-text-editor) is still relevant here because those same restrictions apply to `/dev/stderr`.

## How to make a second pipeline

You have a command that produces both standard output and standard error, and you want to `paste` those two lines next to each other.  That means two concurrent pipes, one for each column.  The shell pipeline `... | ...` provides one of those, and you're going to need to create the second yourself, and redirect STDERR into that using `2>filename`.

```
mkfifo RHS
bb 2>RHS | paste /dev/stdin RHS
```

If this is for use in a script, you may prefer to make that FIFO in a temporary directory, and remove it after use.

Comment: Good answer.  Please note that I'm specifically interested in `/dev/stdin`.  Maybe my `seq 2` example is vague and confusing, since this is the 2nd time somebody's suggested merely *simulating* the desired `paste` output.  ... See revised question text for possible disambiguation.

Comment: @agc the revision doesn't make any difference. You still need to send bb's stderr somewhere that `paste` can read from, and `/dev/stderr` is not that place. In practice, you can send bb's stderr to a pipe/FIFO file, and have `paste` read from that in addition to stdin.

Comment: @muru, You are correct and we agree that functionally `bb()` makes no difference and is in that sense unnecessary, but it is hoped that for presentation purposes `bb()` may help some readers focus more on the general problem rather that any superficial aspects.

Comment: @agc You say you're specifically interested in `/dev/stdin`, but that's not the problem here.  `bb`'s standard output is connected to `paste`'s standard input, and those lines (the raw numbers) are going through exactly as you intend.  The command hangs because of what you're trying to do with `/dev/stderr`.  The modified numbers (`e1`, `e2` etc.) go straight to the console, and `paste` hangs while trying to read from its own standard error.  `paste <anything> /dev/stderr` will have the same effect.

Comment: Updated to use the OP's `bb` function.  That should make the explanation simpler because there are no other pipelines and redirections to distract.  Neither this, nor my earlier revision, were "simulating" the `paste` output; it's using `paste` directly.

Answer (score 3):

`annotate-output` is able to do that because it's doing something special (namely it redirects the stderr of a command to a fifo), something that `paste` has **absolutely** no way of doing -- simply because `paste` is **not** running itself the command(s) it gets its input from, and it has no way of redirecting their input or their output.

But you could write a wrapper that use exactly the same trick annotate-output is using:

```
pasteout(){
  f=$(mktemp -u) || return
  mkfifo -m 600 -- "$f" || return
  "$@" 2>"$f" | paste -- - "$f"
  rm -f -- "$f"
}
pasteout bb
```

Note however that it's prone to dead-locks. If for instance `bb` produces more standard output than can fit in the pipe plus the extra amount initially read by `paste` but doesn't produce any error output, `paste` will be blocked waiting for input on the fifo and will not empty the pipe `bb` is feeding its stdout to, causing `bb`'s write()s to the pipe to hang as well.

Comment: This is a nice tidy wrapper function equivalent of [*JigglyNaga's* FIFO-based answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474308/165517).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the whole line that we need to analyze, that is:

```
seq 2 | tee >(sed 's/^/e/' > /dev/stderr) | paste /dev/stdin /dev/stderr
```

## stderr

First, the last command. Only *stdout* can pass through a pipe:

```
$ seq2 | paste -
1
2

$ seq2 | paste - -
1 2
```

There is nothing to read from `stderr`:

```
$ seq 2 | paste - /dev/stderr 
1   ^C
```

You need to `^C` it because it blocks, there is nothing to read from `stderr`.
Even if you create some output to `stderr` it doesn't travel through a pipe:

```
$ { seq 2; seq 3 4 >/dev/stderr; } | paste - /dev/stderr
1   3
4
```

Exactly as before, the `1` gets printed and the `paste` blocks waiting for `stderr`.
The other 2 numbers went directly to the console and got (independently) printed.

You could give some input to `stderr` in the last command of the pipe:

```
$ { seq 2; seq 3 4 >/dev/stderr; } | paste - /dev/stderr 2</dev/null
1
2
3
4
```

Which is exactly the same as `2>/dev/null` by the way, to avoid blocking the second file descriptor used in the `paste` command. But the values printed come directly from the `seq 3 4` redirected to the console, not from `paste`. This does the same:

```
$ { seq 2; seq 3 4 >/dev/tty; } | paste - /dev/stderr 2</dev/null
1   
2   
3
4
```

And this doesn't block:

```
$ seq 2 | tee >(sed 's/^/e/' > /dev/stderr) | 
  paste /dev/stdin /dev/stderr 2</dev/null
1   
2   
e1
e2
```

## order

Second, the output of `tee` doesn't have to be "in order". [`tee` and `bash` process substitution order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406334/265604)

And, in fact: The output of a process substitution doesn't have to be "in order":
[The process substitution output is out of the order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403783/265604)

```
$ echo one; echo two > >(cat); echo three;
one
three
two
```

In fact, on some examples, if you try several times, you could get different orders. [non-deterministic output from independent processes run concurrently by process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/415358/265604)

```
$ printf '%s\n' {0..1000} | tee >(head -n2) >(sort -grk1,1 | head -n3) >/dev/null
1000
999
998
0
1
```

So, no, it could not be done with process substitution and paste.
You need to give some order to the execution:

```
$ seq 2 | { while read a; do printf "%s %s\n" "$a" "e$a" ; done; }
1 e1
2 e2
```

## bb

So, your bb function, which (basically) contains:

```
| tee >(sed 's/^/e/')
```

Which could be tested with :

```
$ printf '%s\n' {0..1000} | tee >(sort -grk1,1 | head -n3 >&2) | head -n 2
0
1
291
290
289
```

Should print 0, 1, 1000, 999, 998, In that order, but many times it doesn't.
That is: It is **intrinsically** in-stable.

## Stable real Solution.

The only safe solution for bb is to avoid any process substitution.
And, taking advantage that the `{…}` capture both stdout and stderr, example:

```
$ bash -c '{ echo test-str >/dev/stderr; }' 2>/dev/null
```

No output, remove the 2 to confirm.

This will work for bb:

```
$ bb() { seq 5 | tee /dev/stderr | sed 's/^/e/'; }
```

And use a fifo for paste:

```
$ mkfifo out2
$ bb 2>out2  | paste out2 -
1   e1
2   e2
3   e3
4   e4
5   e5
```

You will need to set a trap to remove the fifo file and test if the fifo file exist before creating it.

Seems to work portably on all shells (compatible with Almquist syntax) I tested. Not fully tested, ask for confirmation from other users, there may be some yet unknown surprises.

Comment: Wow, on my system that `printf '%s\n' {0..1000} | tee >(sort -grk1,1 | head -n3 >&2) | head -n 2` is practically a random number generator.

Comment: `| tee /dev/stdout |`?  ITYM `| tee /dev/stderr |`.